# Why can't I install from the live CD?

Tags: installation, live-cd

My install isn't working for some odd reason. After I enter the user info it sits there and then crashes and says:

> The Installer encountered an Unrecoverable error. A desktop will now
>   be now run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing
>   again.

I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then it brings me to the desktop.

This is with the 12.04 LTS desktop CD. No errors were found when I did "Check disc for defects".

Comment: Same problem here. Swizman's solution worked indeed. (altough the credits go this guy 'pecherie' in this forum : http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=9256801#p9256801 ).
Seems to happen on older AMD machines only. (didn't have the problem on newer core i5 & 7 systems)
Nevertheless , would be better to remove this 'ubiquity-slideshow'alltogether from that iso ,no ? configuration : AMD2500+ , 1Gb Ram - 160Gb HD (IDE) , Asrock KS41 motherboard. Problem mentioned in these bugreports :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/959251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably possible to work on this problem further to figure out what's going wrong...but it may be easier for you to just download the [alternate CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) and try installing with that.

Get the `.iso` image with `alternate` in its name and with `i386` if you want the 32-bit version or `amd64` if you want the 64-bit version, regardless of whether your CPU is Intel or AMD.

Answer (score 2):

First remove the installer slide show from the live CD before Installing:

Software center > All files > search for "ubiquity-slideshow" > Click on button "Remove"

> wait until button "Install" comes up (may take a while).

After this: Installer will work now.

Comment: It may... Any reasoning to back this up?